# What does EA compliance mean for java application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can anyone guide me to any links or shed some light on what EA compliant application (my java EAR) signify and what are its advantages. On a side note, I try to deploy java web application on Websphere 7.
EDIT: EA is for Enterprise-appliance.

Thanks.

Comment: I found this http://ocio.os.doc.gov/s/groups/public/@doc/@os/@ocio/@oitpp/documents/content/prod01_004196.pdf

Comment: I think EA in web applications stands for Enterprise Appliance. The link is about Enterprise architecture.

Comment: You should clarify in the question what particularly you mean if you use ambiguous acronyms